# React axis post request returns empty data object but POSTMAN returns data

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman

My axios request is formed like this:

```
    const query = JSON.stringify({'username': 'testuser'})
    const headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    useEffect( () => {
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            url: 'http://54.158.146.220/FetchSongs.php',
            data: query
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
    }, [url])
```

but submitting this request gives me response 200 with no data, even though when I send it with postman it shows the data.

Comment: You can generate code from postman and check what is different between requests

Comment: @Raz Ok but it can't be done in react. Do you see anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t get anything in the body because you don’t pass the data correctly, when the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the data (your `query` variable) shouldn’t be JSON format.

> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: the keys and values are encoded in key-value tuples separated by `&` with a `=` between the key and the value. Non-alphanumeric characters in both keys and values are percent encoded: this is the reason why this type is not suitable to use with binary data (use `multipart/form-data` instead)
>
> From [MDN - POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

To pass the data in the right format you can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)